# Unable to get Active user's email

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I tried to log the user's email for debugging purposes. I used `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`. I received the following error.

> Exception: You do not have permission to call Session.getActiveUser.getEmail() Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

Hence i added the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` scope to my addon. Now I get the following error

> The script does not have permission to get the active user's identity.

However, I don't see the error if I run it on my account(Gsuite) or any other users in our domain. FYI: I am the owner of the addon.

Am I missing any scopes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing `getActiveUser()` by `getEffectiveUser()` seem to make it work.

Comment: Do you know **why** the getActiveUser() didn't work?

Comment: getEffectiveUser() gets the User under whose authentication the WebApp was published. If you want to get the User accessing the WebApp, you will have to use getActiveUser().

Comment: This did nothing to fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best explanation is in [the official docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser). Addon users context does not assume obligatory authorization and getEmail method may return a blank string.

Comment: Oh ok. Since, we request permissions for email using oauth, I thought we should have access to their email address.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `getActiveUser()` nor `getEffectiveUser()` were working for me.
There's an issue open with Google right now and some suggestions in [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149413836) thread helped me:

(1) Try copying the scopes from (File->Project Properties->Scopes)  into the manifest file (View->Show Manifest File) following the instructions give [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes).

(2) The issue is with the *new App Script runtime powered by Chrome v8*. If (1) doesn't work (it didn't work for me) --> disable the App Script runtime as follows: (Run -> Disable App Script runtime powered by Chrome V8). The project will now run with Apps Script Legacy which does not have this issue.

**Note:** (2) is applicable until the issue is resolved.